# Bootstrap navbar can't add active with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, navbar

I used Bootstrap , now I want to add `active` for the new navbar title when I jump to the new page, but the `active` cann't dynamic display , unless I manually refresh the new page.

The Html codes:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav " data-in="fadeInDown" data-out="fadeOutUp">
  <li class="NavHead active"> <a href="/">Home</a></li>
  <li class="NavHead"> <a href="/questions">Questions</a></li>
  <li class="NavHead"> <a href="/tags" >Tags</a></li>
  <li class="NavHead"> <a href="/knowledges" >Knowledges</a></li>
  <li class="NavHead"> <a href="/company">Company</a></li>
  <li class="NavHead"> <a href="/activity">Activity</a></li>
</ul>
```

The JavaScript codes:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    $(function () {
        $(".navbar-nav").find(".NavHead").each(function () {
            if ($("a",this).attr("href") === window.location.pathname) {
                $(this).addClass("active");
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass("active");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

How should I to revise the JS?

Comment: You don't need twice `$.ready` functions. Are your clicks AJAX based?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't understand how to `clicks AJAX based`....And I delete the `$(document).ready(function()})`  ,just use the `$(function()...});`  it also doesn't work ...

Comment: did you checked my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code for add active class for the new navbar title when I jump to the new page

```js
$('ul li a').click(function(){
    $('li a').parent().removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had try with your codes , but it doesn't work either, the new nav item doesn't have `active`  unless I manually refresh the new page and the nav item `Home` always has `active`....

Comment: I would use `$(".navbar-nav .NavHead")...` instead of `$(".navbar-nav").find(".NavHead")...`. @sylor_huang  `console.log(window.location.pathname)` prints the same value that your `href`'s? Just doing some sanity check.

Comment: You can try $(window).on('hashchange'). I have added to my code.

Comment: I had try with  `$(".navbar-nav .NavHead")...` also , when I click the new item ,  the `Home` `active` is always displaying and the new nav item doesn't has `active` unless I manually refresh the new page, so when I refresh the new page , there are two `active` display...

Comment: need to change Home href <a href="/index">Home</a>

Comment: o.o , it also doesn't work ... I try with your new codes , when I click the new item , the nav always display the `Home` `active` and the new nav item doesn't has `active` no matter whether I manually refresh the new page...

Comment: I use rails4.2.8 , and the html use Bootstrap 3.3.7

Comment: do you try $(window).on('hashchange')?

Comment: Yes , I had try with `$(window).on('hashchange')...`, the nav also always display the `Home` `active` and the new nav item doesn't has `active` no matter whether I manually refresh the new page...

Comment: please try this `$('ul li a').click(function(){
    $('li a').parent().removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
});`

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry to  reply  to you so late  @Mohammad Ali Rony , and with your new codes , it alse doesn't work , and the nav also always display the `Home `  ` active` , and never display the new item `active` ...

Comment: Do you have the same tree ul --> li --> a? can you please try this  `$('.navbar-nav a').click(function(){
    $('.navbar-na a').parent().removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
});`

Comment: Yes, I have the same DOM tree, and your new codes also have the same result as the `$('ul li a').click(function(){ $('li a').parent().removeClass("active"); $(this).parent().addClass("active"); });`  And now I have another thinking .  As my question codes , I found that as long as I refresh the new page , it can get the new page `active` , so is there any method that when I  load there :  `...$(this).addClass("active");...`   and then to refresh the new page?

Comment: you check your console `$('.navbar-nav a').click(function(){
    console.log('onclick')
    $('.navbar-na a').parent().removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
});`

Comment: I had check many times , the `console.log('onclick')`  shows nothing...

Comment: Hi , Mohammad Ali Rony , I had paste my original js codes in my footer.html , and it works as my except...thanks a lot for your answer patiently...Best day~~~

Comment: @sylor_huang  Can you please mark this answer correct if answered is useful.

Comment: Hi , Mohammad Ali Rony,A moment ago ,I found that I was used rails4.2.8, and when I remove the tubrolinks , the js files in <head></head> also works good.

Answer (score 0):

Praveen is right, you have two `document.ready` function. Here's how I did it (just tweaking some part of your code):

```
$(function () {
    $(".navbar-nav").find(".NavHead").each(function () {
        if ($(this).children('a').attr("href") === window.location.pathname) {
            $(this).addClass("active");
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("active");
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your help . I had try with your codes , when I click the new item , the nav always display the `Home`  `active` and  the new nav item doesn't has `active` unless I manually refresh the new page, too...

Answer (score 0):

I had soluve my questions just need to paste the js codes in my footer.html , and it works as my except . Maybe there are best way to solve this problem ...

the js codes like this :

```
<script>
  $(function () {
      $(".navbar-nav .NavHead").each(function () {
          if ($("a",this).attr("href") === location.pathname) {
              $(this).addClass("active");
              return true;
          } else {
              $(this).removeClass("active");
          }
      });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: A moment ago ,I found that I was used rails4.2.8, and when I remove the `tubrolinks` , the js files in <head></head> also works good.